# How to get call_once() to work correctly in a constructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have tested the use of **call_once**() with variables in a multi-threaded context and the behavior is as expected.

However, I have difficulty in getting **call_once**() to work correctly with constructors, in a multi-threaded context.

The following [program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b55dd5e6cda9bb8a) has been written for this. It is a modification of an example provided by Stroustrup, in "CPL", 4th Ed.

```
/** 
    initialize_once_class_ctor.cpp

    Demonstrate the use of the once_flag type and the call_once() function
    to implement lazy initialization of a class' constructor.

**/

#include <mutex>    // once_flag, call_once()
#include <thread>   // thread
#include <iostream> // cout

using namespace std;

class X
{
private:
   static int data;
   static once_flag initdata_flg;

   static void init();

public:
   X()
   {
      call_once(initdata_flg, init);

      cout << "** diagnostic: X::data initialized"
           << endl; 
   }

   int getdata() const
   {
      return data;
   }
};


/** class X static members ...
    (static members must be defined 
    outside the class **/
int X::data;
once_flag X::initdata_flg;

void X::init()
{
   data = 915;
}


/// declarations ...

/// implementation ...

int main()
{
   thread t1 {X::X};
   thread t2 {X::X};

   t1.join();
   t2.join();
}
```

The program gives compilation errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:57:19: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
    thread t1 {X::X};
                   ^

In file included from main.cpp:10:
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:118:7: note: candidate: 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)'
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:118:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:57:19: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'
    thread t1 {X::X};
                   ^

In file included from main.cpp:10:
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:113:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)'
     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:113:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::thread&&'
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:106:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread()'
     thread() noexcept = default;
     ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:106:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

main.cpp:58:19: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
    thread t2 {X::X};
                   ^

In file included from main.cpp:10:
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:118:7: note: candidate: 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)'
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
       ^~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:118:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:58:19: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'
    thread t2 {X::X};
                   ^

In file included from main.cpp:10:
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:113:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)'
     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
     ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:113:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::thread&&'
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:106:5: note: candidate: 'std::thread::thread()'
     thread() noexcept = default;
     ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/8.1.0/thread:106:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

How can I fix these compilation errors?

Comment: std::thread() takes a function as a parameter. A constructor is not a function. What do you want the thread to do? Whatever that is, make it a function and pass the function to the thread constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor can never be called directly (as a function). Typing e.g. `X{}` or `X()` is syntax for creating a (temporary) object of type `X`, *not* for calling the constructor of `X`. The constructor gets called as part of creating the object, but that's internal.

`std::thread` requires a callable, and a constructor can never be one. You can provide a lambda instead:

```
auto f = []{ X{}; };

thread t1 {f};
thread t2 {f};
```

Comment: True that.  But can that be what the OP wants to do? Create an X that promptly goes out of existence?

Comment: @JiveDadson, Angew's solution works. I have tested it using a function, rather than a lambda, and its fine. My intent is only to see how to use call_once() with constructors; I don't need the object per se.